# magento 2.1.2 installation stuck on Theme

Tags: magento2, magento-ce

I'm trying to install magento 2.1.2 on CentOs host but its just stuck withot any error

```
Module 'Magento_Theme':

Installing data...
```

what should i do?

Comment: Try restart installation process

Comment: @KAndy  
 
i tried more than 10 times always same problem

Comment: Ok.
Enable error display (in php config or in bootstrap.php).
Also try to disable memory and time limits for php cli if any. Rerun.
Do you have some errors in magento_root/var/log/* logs or php logs files.

Comment: @KAndy in magento_root/var/log/* i have 2 file 1-debug.log 2-install.log. i set time limit(max_execution_time) to 180.000 and memory to -1(without limit)

Comment: Set max_execution_time = 3600 in php.ini